# Google MAP API v3: Link markers to an external list

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Given is a database with locations, we feed those tho the google map api and all points are displayed. Now there is a list of this location right next to the google map. How can i link the places in the list to the dots on the map? Can i just give some kind of ID to each marker?

Like this:
http://www.local.ch/en/q/ubs.html

I want to light up the point on the map on the list item hover and open the info-box by clicking on the list item.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok was lucky and found my answer in other toppic:
[Google Maps for Absolute Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767641/google-maps-for-absolute-dummies) thx to John Hartsock for this link.

changing the marker icon on hover on a external list:
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/mouseover.htm

very useful google map tutorials:
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/