# Google Maps for Absolute Dummies

Tags: google-maps

I just signed up for a Google Maps API key and was hoping for a wizard style application for setting up the map (not a static one), unfortunately I was immediately blinded by science!

Can anyone point me to a tutorial where I can find out how to create a simple google map and place a callout bubble including am image of the office and address details.

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for Google maps is pretty fantastic. That's how I learned to use it.

There's a section for [Basics](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/introduction.html) in the docs. That might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is show a map with an infowindow, you might want to take a look at the embedding options here:
http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/quick.html

It'll let you easily embed a map on your site, without to much science!

Answer (score 0):

*Shameless self-promotion*

If you are happy to use C# this may or may not help - [Lookup on all postcodes on a webpage, and plot them with Google maps](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/csharp-google-maps-postcode-parser.aspx). It doesn't really need much ASP.NET/C# knowledge beyond the basics.

Comment: Thanks everybody for you advice! I was able to put together this map but I now have a problem with Internet explorer. It is showing black where the shadow under the location information bubble should be. Works fine in finrefox.

Anybody know how to fix this? Or at the very worst disable the shadows underneath altogether?

Many thanks!
Decbrad

Comment: here's what I managed to put together... http://www.sportingemporium.com/google-map.htm

Comment: @Decbrad Looks good. You could disable the shadows or report it as a bug to Google